# SublimeREPL: Not able to find sublimeREPL in package control: install package

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimerepl, package-control

I am trying to run Scala from Sublime text 3 and want to enable console input.

I found out that it can be done using SublimeREPL.

But i am not able to find that in Package Control: Install Package

[image: It only shows these options]

I also searched under "Package Control: Enable package", There also SublimeREPL doesn't show up.

Any ideas what may be wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There were recently some problems accessing the Package Control servers at https://packagecontrol.io. First see if you can access the web site through your web browser, then if so restart Sublime and select `Package Control: Install Package` again from the Command Palette to see if it's listed now. Also, I'd recommend typing in `SublimeREPL` so you don't get the other results.

Comment: Thanks @MattDMo for Reply.
I am not able to reach packagecontrol.io from my browser. Moreover, now when i try to see all packages available under Package control install, it says "There are no packages available for installation". Tried deleting the package Control.sublime-package and reinstalling it. That didn't help. Any suggestions are most welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MattDMo today i am able to reach packagecontrol.io, but while trying to see the packages available for installation under PCI, i still see "there are no packages available for installation" message. Can you please share your views about this?

Comment: The website is still messed up for me. The search function is good and broken - I searched for a dozen common packages, and it couldn't find any of them. The problem is that [Linode](https://www.linode.com/), Package Control's hosting provider, has been under a [DDoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) since Dec. 25. Monitor @ linode on Twitter for news, and @wbond for Package Control updates.

Comment: Thanks @MattDMo for your help. Much appreciated.